# Appleの規約が更新されて `14. Personal attacks` 部分がよくわかりません。

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, apple

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#personal-attacks

> 14.3 Apps that display user generated content must include a method for filtering objectionable material, a mechanism for users to flag offensive content, and the ability to block abusive users from the service

部分なのですが、これって以下の認識であっていますか？また、この部分でリジェクトされた方がいましたら、どのように対応しましたか？

- CGM系アプリでは、以下の機能をすべて有する必要がある。
- 1. ユーザーが不愉快だと思うコンテンツをフィルタリングする機能
- 2. ユーザーが攻撃的なコンテンツだと思ったことを知らせることができる機能
- 3. サービス側が悪質なユーザーをブロックできる機能

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

個人的な経験はありませんが、英語の理解としては問題ないかと思います。

[こちらの方のブログ](http://feedtailor.jp/staff/2014/11/17/627)が参考になりそうです。具体的に Twitter や Facebook がどうしているかも述べられています。